# Date in CET timezone to user's timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a list of list of string dates like this: `'17/12/2017 19:34'`. They are `CET` dates.

How can I transform it to the user's browser date?

I'm doing this:

```
const tzGuess = moment.tz.guess()

export const toTimeZone = (time) => {
  const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
  return moment(time, format).tz(tzGuess).format(format)
}

console.log(toTimeZone('17/12/2017 19:34', tzGuess))
```

but how can I say to `moment` that the date I'm passing at first is a `CET` one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) function for parsing time string using a given timezone (e.g. `'Europe/Madrid'`).

The issue is: what do you mean with CET? If your input has fixed UTC+1 offset (like Central European Time), then you can use RobG's solution. If you have to consider both CET and CEST, I think that the best soution is to use  [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/).

Here a live code sample:

```js
const tzGuess = moment.tz.guess()

const toTimeZone = (time) => {
  const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
  return moment.tz(time, format, 'Europe/Madrid').tz(tzGuess).format(format)
}

console.log(toTimeZone('17/12/2017 19:34', tzGuess))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

A great resource about timezone is the [timezone tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Madrid observes daylight saving (CEST) from the end of March to the end of October. The OP seems to want only CET.

Answer (score 1):

Without moment.js, parse the string to a Date, treating it as UTC, then adjust for the CET offset (+0100). You can then format it using local time values for the client:

```js
// Parse date in format DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
// Adjust for CET timezone
function parseCET(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  // Subtract 1 from month and hour
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0], b[3]-1, b[4]));
  return d;
}

var s = '17/12/2017 19:34';
console.log(parseCET(s).toString());
```

However, if the time needs to observe daylight saving (CEST) for the source time stamp, you'll need to account for that.